# C# LoadLibrary ERROR_NO_TOKEN

Tags: c#, loadlibrary, kernel32

I'm loading a MFC dll with dependencies (let's say I'm loading D.dll, which depends on C.dll, B.dll and A.dll) in C#.
Here's my code:

```
[DllImport( "kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true )]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary( string lpFileName );

private void btn_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
int             nUltErr;
string          strDLL;
StringBuilder   strPDF;
StringBuilder   strXML;

strDLL = "C:\\DEVELOP\\Libs\\Interfaccia\\Interfaccia_C_2005\\DLL\\Interfaccia_C_2005.dll";
strFile1 = new StringBuilder( @"C:\DEVELOP\Libs\Interfaccia\TestCase\PROGRAM\tiger.pdf" );
strFile2 = new StringBuilder( @"C:\DEVELOP\Libs\Interfaccia\TestCase\PROGRAM\tiger.XML" );
if( LoadLibrary( strDLL ) != IntPtr.Zero )
{
    LoadPDF( strPDF );
    SaveXML( strXML );
    ClosePDF();
    FreeMemory();
}
else
{
    nUltErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    MessageBox.Show( "Errore nel caricamento della dll." );
}
```

}

nUltErr is 1008 = 0x3F0, that should be ERROR_NO_TOKEN.
What does exactly mean this in C#?
Path to DLL IS right.

Comment: `DllImportAttribute.SetLastError` is `false` by default. Your import definition doesn't change default behavior. Set `SetLastError = true` explicitly to get error code, caused by `LoadLibrary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` generally means that someone has attempted to call `OpenThreadToken` on a thread that was not impersonating. This may be a problem or not a problem - that's just the last error code to be recorded by `SetlastError`.

This call could be in the `DllMain` of `Interfaccia_C_2005.dll`, or in the `DllMain` of any library which is referenced in turn. It is not entirely obvious why they would need to do that but it is possible.

Also, this may not be the actual error causing failure. Among other causes, `LoadLibrary` will fail if the `DllMain` of `Interfaccia_C_2005.dll`, or in the `DllMain` of any library which is referenced in turn, returns false. If the DllMain returns false, without calling `SetLastError`, GetLastError will show the ***previous*** error, whatever it was. For example the system might be quite happy for `OpenThreadToken` to fail, but something else has gone wrong, which did not call `SetLastError`.

Essentially you need to fire up the Native Code debugger, and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not set the `SetLastError` field on your `DllImport` attribute.

This means you are not getting the correct value from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`.

Change LoadLibrary to this:

```
[DllImport( "kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true )]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary( string lpFileName );
```