# ERROR_NO_TOKEN after call to WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()

Tags: .net, impersonation

I am using @MattJohnson's technique for impersonating a new user using C# on .NET 4.0 on a Windows 2008 R2 domain, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net). I manage to log on the user successfully, and the call to `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` runs silently, returning an apparently valid context. However, when I check the last error number by using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` right after this, I get the value 1008 aka ERROR_NO_TOKEN.

If I let my code run, it behaves as the new user is logged on (i.e. `Environment.UserName` returns the new user's name) until I dispose of the handle; however, no impersonation occurs, because the access rights of my code are still those of the original user.

I have spent some time googling about this, but I found no conclusive answer as why `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` may cause an ERROR_NO_TOKEN error, or how to overcome it. Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**. I just found out about the following. When I run Visual Studio normally, my code behaves as described above. However, when I run Visual Studio as an admin (i.e. right-click, Run as Administrator), then impersonation works perfectly, although I still get ERROR_NO_TOKEN from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. I might as well ignore this error code since impersonation works, but I would need to run my code with elevated privileges. Isn't this odd?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16567631/634824) help?

Comment: @MattJohnson: Thanks. As far as I understand, this means that the error may come from any intermediate library call. Any idea on how to detect where the problem is exactly? Thank you.

Comment: Speculating, but perhaps could this be a multi-threading issue?  I never encountered that error myself.  Perhaps someone else will come along with more details.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Unlikely, but I just updated my question with some new findings.